# What's the most efficient way to erase set of elements from std::set?

Tags: c++, set, erase

I have to to remove some elements from a std::set S. I have a set of elements to be removed, but not all of them are actually belong to S. It seems I can't use "erase( iterator first, iterator last )" since according to 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase 
range [first; last) must be a valid range in S. 
I can perform the task using std::set_difference or introducing yet another container, but what's the most efficient way to erase set of elements from std::set?

Comment: When in doubt about performance, think (e.g. big O), and if thinking says it matters, **measure**. How to do things most efficiently might depend on the set item type and its comparison function, as well as what knowledge you have to items to be removed, e.g. are they consecutive values? When you're concerned about performance, are you sure that you need the ordering of a `std::set`, or can you make do with a `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: Loop over the elements to remove, and call `S.erase(value)` for each of them.

Comment: Effective or efficient?

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks - edited.

Comment: so does your set contain references? Container objects have to be copyable and assignable

Comment: You could also just create a set of items to delete, then loop through and delete the items in the first set based on the items in the second set. This is reasonably efficient for hash-based (O(1)) data structures like the one you mentioned